# Jquery - add css :active style inline

Tags: jquery

How to add :active pceudo class so that button will translate onclick without separated global css?

```
const $button = $('<button></button>').css({
      margin: '5px',
      ':active': 'transform: translate(0, 3px)',
    })
```

Comment: Don't think you can add stuff like `:active` with jquery

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen so i need to make onclick function wrapper for buttons with translate action? Or maybe there is a way to make create and inject stylescheet with jquery?

Comment: better option to add a new class with this :active property

Comment: @Atul can you give an example in answer?

Comment: Sure, you can do what I said I got a better Idea now. Just check answer if this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement what I understood is , on click you want to translate Y the button to 3px and as soon as mouse button left it should be back to normal position , which means Translate Y 0px.

So how :active actually work is , it get activated as soon as you click on something and deactivate when you left your mouse button.
Like this: With CSS:

```css
    button {
       color: red;
      background: white;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px 40px;
      display: block;
    }
    button:active {
      transform: translate(0px,3px);
    }
```

```html
    <button>Click</button>
```

NOw check same thing with JQuery.

```js
$("button").mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('transform','translate(0,3px)')
});
$("button").mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('transform','translate(0,0px)')
});
```

```css
button {
   color: red;
  background: white;
border: 2px solid;
padding: 20px 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Just let me know If I misunderstood your requirement,

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can inject styles in head:

```
$('head').append('<style>.myClass:hover { background-color: red; }</style>')
$('<button>123</button>').addClass('myClass')
```